# Upload object to Google Firebase Cloud Storage with Content Length

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload the file to Google Firebase Cloud Storage with Content-Length and retrieve it from Android HttpURLConnection, but now when I'm receiving the storage object through the below URL, it's not returning the Content-Length instead I'm getting -1.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/PATH
```

Even I've added all the required headers as below.

```js
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

My upload source code,

```js
admin.storage().bucket().upload(file, {
    destination: 'some_path/some_file.ext',
    public: true,
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=0',
    }
})
```

Java code from Android

```java
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strings[1]);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        // TODO
        publishProgress(1);
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            if (fileLength > 0) {
                int progress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                publishProgress(progress);
            }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail what you're observing and what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: could you share with us the complete trace you are getting?